# CSS file IE firefox chrome

Tags: css

In my css file I have the following code and want it to applied on caption of my table

```
 caption 
 {
 color:green;
 font-style:bold;
 }
```

my html file

```
<html> <head>

<link href="mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<title>Home Page - My Schedule</title> </head> <body>

<center> <h2>write your name here...</h2> 

<a href="index.html">Home Page</a>  <a href="CV.html">My CV</a>  <a href="Schedule.html">My Schedule</a>  <a href="Icourses.html">My Courses</a>  <a href="Banner.html">Banner</a> <a href="Links.html">Links</a> <a href="Frames.html">Frames</a>

<br/> <table border="1" width="800" height="300" align="center"> <caption><h3>My Schedule</h3></caption>

<br/> <thead> <tr align="center"> <td><img src="img3.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="280"></td> <td colspan="4"><center><h4>write your name here - level 4</h4> </td> </tr> </thead> <tr align="center"> <td>1</td> <td>Web Design</td> <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" >Off</td> <td colspan="2">management</td> </tr> <tr align="center"> <td>2</td> <td>management</td> <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" colspan="3">Off</td> </tr> <tr align="center"> <td>3</td> <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Off</td> <td >management</td> <td colspan="3">management</td> </tr> <tr align="center"> <td>4</td> <td>Web Design</td> <td>management</td> <td>math</td> <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Off</td> </tr> <tr align="center"> <td>5</td> <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" colspan="4">Off</td> </tr> </table> 



<a href="index.html">Go Back</a>  </center> </body> </html>
```

but the problem is that code working fine on IE but not working on Firefox and Chrome. I tried to clear cache but nothing help.

Secondly, I have my website in the following path

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\My Website
```

and my css file in the following path

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\My Website\styles
```

and I am not able to link css file when its in this subfolder

I tried the following code

```
<link href="../mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="../styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but not working.

Comment: The web developer's mantra: "If it works in IE, but not the other browsers, your code is wrong." Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work. Inept at best, it's the worst browser on the planet.

Comment: It works in IE, but not standards-compliant browsers? What black magic is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<link href="mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

With

```
<link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

You haven't told your HTML file that the `mystyles.css` file is in the `styles` folder.

**FYI**..

`<link href="../mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Would be `C:\Users\user\Desktop\mystles.css`

and

`<link href="../styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Would be `C:\Users\user\Desktop\styles\mystles.css`

Comment: Do you mean compatibility? All browsers understand the `<link>` tag.

Comment: No I mean that the css file has been applied on IE but NOT working on friefox and chrome they are dont take the effect :S

Comment: ;) No problem - Please accept this answer if it has solved your problem. You should also consider going back to previous questions and accepting appropriate answers.

Comment: That must be another issue there is no reason why Firefox and Chrome doesn't understand that line.

Comment: The link element is not allowed to have a closing / as shown and is invalid. Remove the slash.